# SMTP-сервер, команда "BDAT"

Tags: c#, smtp

Добрый день!

Я пишу свой СМТП-сервер, и столкнулся с ситуацией - после того как клиент передает мне команду "BDAT" и непосредственно само письмо, диалог моего сервера с клиентом как-бы зависает, т.е. я шлю ему ответ "250 ОК", а он мне в ответ ничего.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно должен происходить диалог команды BDAT?**

Comment: Далась вам эта BDAT ... Ее кто нибудь кроме MS Exchange вообще поддерживает ? А так, судя по RFC вы все правильно делаете, там конечно в образцах в стандарте всякие разные тексты еще к 250 но они же по идее опциональны и стандартом не регулируются. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1830

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было после каждого куска сообщения (chunk) отправлять код "250 ОК" а не один раз в конце. Проблема так решилась.